# Responsive height on div with wordpress page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

How can I make a div which I display content in from wordpress page.php responsive to the Wordpress page height. Here is how I display the page on my website.

```
<?php 
        while(have_posts()) {
            the_post(); ?>
    <div class="page-content">
        <h1> <?php the_title(); ?> </h1>


        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
```

And the css:

```
.page-content {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%;
    height: 135vh;
    border: 1px black solid;
    margin-left: 5%;
    padding: 16px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Can I make the height of the div the same as the height on the wp page?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem. I didn't understand what you mean by wp page height.

Comment: I want the height of my div to be the same height as the wordpress page.

Comment: Please share some screenshots. I still didn't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the height of the div in your page, don't force the height and add

```
min-height : 100vh
```

From what I understand